# Is it possible to use a class method to initialize a final attribute in Dart?

Tags: dart

Let's say I have a class that contains a function passed during its initialization:

```dart
class Caller {
  final _controller = StreamController<int>();

  Caller(void Function(int) callback) {
      _controller.stream.listen(callback);
  }

  void send(int x) {
    _controller.sink.add(x)
  }
}
```

Is is possible to initialize a `Caller` with another class method while also marking it as `final`?

```dart
class Container {
  final Caller _caller;
  int _val = 0;

  void _doSomething(int x) {
    _val += x;
    _caller.send(_val);
  }

  Container() : _caller = Caller(_doSomething);
}
```

Dart complains that `"Only static members can be accessed in initializers."` I understand that you can't access uninitialized parameters before the constructor is called, but isn't a "method" actually final by default? It cannot be modified dynamically unlike other attributes.

So, it there any workaround beside marking `_caller` non-final and initializing it in the constructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

You currently cannot create two objects which refer to each other only through final fields, or which pass each other to the other ones' constructor. Final fields must be initialized before any references to the object becomes available, and there is no way to create both objects before the other.

For this particular situation, you could provide a way to call the `listen` method with a callback *after* creating the `Caller`. You can create the `Caller` before calling `listen`. (I recommend using `forEach` instead of `listen` when you don't use the `StreamSubription` returned by `listen`).

In a future version of the language (along with non-nullable types), we intend to introduce *late* initialized fields. Then it will be possible to write:

```
class Caller {
  final _controller = StreamController<int>();
  Caller(void Function(int) callback) {
    _controller.forEach(callback);
  }
}
class Container {
  late final _caller = Caller(this._doSomething);
  Container() {
    _caller;
  }
  void _doSomething(int x) { ... }
}
```

This late `_caller` field will be initialized the first time you read it. It's still final, and you can force that it's read in the constructor, by reading it. It's a little hackish, mainly because of the spurious read-to-initialize.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed explanation, I really appreciate that! Your suggestion to use a second method is what I had implemented. It doesn't enforce that "the controller should be listened **once and exactly once**", which is why I was wondering if there wasn't another way. Glad to hear about the future `late` keyword. Dart is a very well thought-out and pleasant language by the way.

Answer (score 0):

The `"Only static members can be accessed in initializers."` is about the `_doSomething` method you give as parameter to the `Caller` constructor. Since the `_doSomething` method are not available in the construction step (since the method are member of the object which are yet to be constructed) you cannot use it here.

Comment: I understand that. I'm asking for a possible workaround that would allow me to pass the `_doSomething` to the `Caller` constructor and keep `_caller` as `final`.

Comment: Why is it important that `_caller` is final?

Comment: It's not that much "important", but the `_caller` has little reason to change during the lifetime of `Container`, so I thought that's what the `final` keyword is used for.